# Animation showing last frame when played?

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigging, logic-bricks

To make this simple I have a [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36494) that you can look at. I have simple logic:

1) When the prop "Active" is true, our object is visible. When false, invisible.

2) When Spacebar is hit, "Active" becomes true, and an animation is played.

There is a problem with this: when active becomes true *and* the animation is played (spacebar is hit),  **you can see the last frame of the animation at the very *start* when spacebar is hit, *then* the animation plays.** This seems like a simple error that can be fixed easily. I just need the animation to be played *and* the object to become visible, not both of those *and* a random frame to be displayed. If it seems confusing, look at the .blend I provided. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** It is not the version of the engine for further detail. The simple issue can be fixed by updating the engine. I made this new .blend, which can be found [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38335) containing very similar logic to my scene. The visibility and the action happen *at the same time*, yet, visibility acts first. Open the .blend, hit 2 to make "active" false, then hit 1 to make it true. All you do is hit 2 and 1 with the new .blend, space bar was removed as I tried to replicate my scene.

**EDIT #2**: I just figured out the real reason. It's not the visibility. It's the animation itself. The visibility has *nothing* to do with my scenario. The timing is right, the visibility is occurring as created and implemented. So why is this happening? I changed the animation to work on a property, and it seems that, when you restart the animation, *it slips in one frame of the **original** object*. It *ignores* the property for *one* frame, right before you restart the animation. It doesn't show the end/start off the animation, but the object's original position. How would I know this? I changed the last frame and the first frame separately, and it doesn't "flash" to any of those. It "flashes" to the original object position *ignoring* the animations. What have we concluded? it is the animation itself that causes the issue. When the animation resets, it resets properly but slips in one frame that is not needed, in fact, *not even a part of the property that **controls** the animation*. It seems to be a bug in the engine, but I am not certain. Thanks for all the help though, looking to solve this ASAP. ;)

Comment: @X-27 I added an edit. Read it for more clarification.

Comment: I don't think this is an error. Since the last keyframe of your timeline keeps it up there, when you order it go lower and perform the animation it teleports down there. It happens when it is visible too,but it is more distinct when it toggles from invisibility and does the animation.

On another note, if you press P and then press "space","2","space"(very fast in a row) everything works.But if you press "space","2", then wait for couple of seconds and press "space" again the cube will become visible but the animation won't re-play.You might wanna check that.

Comment: @Lev OK, we made some progress. Thanks for noticing that, but do you have an idea of *how* to fix this?

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. I used a timer to make it invisible for the 1st frame,but it keeps doing it. Do you need the cube to remain at the top position after the animation plays once? Also why do you have that origin point so high?

Comment: Have you tried treating it like the animation was shifted forwards by one frame? You could easily cheat the system by moving the animation back by one frame, so the original first frame is now the last frame, which will be displayed first.

Comment: @Nerfer007 I don't know if it is showing the last frame *or* the original position. I think it is showing the original position because **it works just fine if there is no visibility logic involved**.

Comment: Hmm. It also does the same kind of "flash", when you hit "space", let the animation play half way, hit 2, then hit 1. I'm thinking that there's a slight delay when the message is sent and it becomes activated. I think you could solve it with a python script that starts the animation right before activating the cube (you can't do this with just logic bricks).

Comment: OK, I fiddled with a script (which didn't work), and I'm starting to consider if it's a bug. A work around might be to avoid using the visibility checkbox, and instead use a full alpha material.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue after updating a project from 2.72 to 2.73. Thankfully it's fixed in the 2.76 release candidate. Confirmed the same with your file.

Comment: I tried to move the last keyframe to frame 19 and copy the first keyframe to frame 20. The animation shows actually the last frame, not the original position. I think the animation chain sets the visibility FIRST, THEN it moves the item down. I tried to add a DELAY actuator, but PLAY is not trigged until ACTIVE is TRUE.

Comment: Fix = update to 2.76, it's a bug

Comment: @pqftgs the version fixes party of the issue, it still doesn't work for me and I put a new .blend that still has the problem which is *still happening* with the *new* version. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for why that's happening.  Even after 8 years the weird quirks and delays behind logic bricks are a complete mystery to me.  However, a fix is to reset the action when Active == False like so: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38338 or better yet I stripped everything out and wrote a script that does not exhibit the issue: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38339

Comment: @pqftgs I see your workaround for the issue, but my scene still wont work. I am on the newest version of blender, and, when I delete all my *other* logic bricks, I am left with the original question's .blend but in my .blend. I am still puzzled why this even happens! When I do what you did, and it turns false, it *flashes as soon as it turns false* then resets the animation. It seems to be a bug that Blender hasn't fixed. Thanks though.

Comment: You'll probably have to share the file then, unless you can replicate it in another.  There's not much else we can do otherwise, unfortunately.

Comment: @pqftgs well other than giving out a .blend or replicating my insanely large logic brick setup, I think the best way is to submit a bug report to fix the main cause of the problem instead of a workaround. I am just not sure how to report one and I was hoping someone would.

Comment: Just realized you were using flipper.  Apparently that's been broken for some time https://developer.blender.org/T46122 You can switch it to Play for the same effect, but it breaks when interrupted mid-way because the actuator never deactivates.  To work around that you can play frames 0 - 0 when Active == False as was done in my previous workaround.  This is expected behavior.